# When or why does clEnqueueNDRangeKernel return Null as event?

Tags: c, concurrency, opencl

Hi I am trying to exectue example code from the book 7 Concurreny Models in 7 weeks. The Author uses a macbook, while I am using a a dell xps with windows 10.

My Program crashes because the `timing_event` is still null after I call the function `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()`.

```
cl_event timing_event;
size_t work_units = NUM_ELEMENTS;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &work_units,
    NULL, 0, NULL,&timing_event);
```

The [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html) state that the follwing about the event parameter

> event
>
> Returns an event object that identifies this particular kernel
>   execution instance. Event objects are unique and can be used to
>   identify a particular kernel execution instance later on. If event is
>   NULL, no event will be created for this kernel execution instance and
>   therefore it will not be possible for the application to query or
>   queue a wait for this particular kernel execution instance.

Can sombody provide some explanation why this happens on my dell and not on the macbook of the author?

Comment: I can speculate that this might be due to using CPU device and small work loads, the implementation decides to execute the task inlined, so there is no execution to keep track of (it is already completed at call return).

Comment: @DarkZeros thanks for your comment. I found the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem did not come from `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()`it happened earlier in `clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);`. I retrieved the build Information with  `clGetProgramBuildInfo()`. The problem was that my **multiply_arrays.cl** file wasn't **utf 8 encoded**

---

For everyone who is new to opencl. Every opencl function returns a status integer which is mapped to an specific error code. If a function does return does not return an status code, it is possible to pass a pointer to the function. See the example functions I linked below. This is very helpful to debug your program.

[Returns Status Code](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramBuildInfo.html)

[Status Code by Reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateProgramWithSource.html)

**main.cpp**

```
/***
* Excerpted from "Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks",
* published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
* Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material,
* courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
* We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose.
* Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/pb7con for more book information.
***/
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#else  
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <chrono>

#define NUM_ELEMENTS (100000)

char* read_source(const char* filename) {
    FILE *h = fopen(filename, "r");
    fseek(h, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t s = ftell(h);
    rewind(h);
    char* program = (char*)malloc(s + 1);
    fread(program, sizeof(char), s, h);
    program[s] = '\0';
    fclose(h);
    return program;
}

void random_fill(cl_float array[], size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        array[i] = (cl_float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
}

int main() {
    //Status for Errorhandling
    cl_int status;

    //Identify Platform
    cl_platform_id platform;
    clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);

    //Get Id of GPU
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_uint num_devices = 0;
    clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, &num_devices);

    // Create Context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);


    //Use context to create Command Queue
    //Que enables us to send commands to the gpu device
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, NULL);

    //Load Kernel
    char* source = read_source("multiply_arrays.cl");
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
        (const char**)&source, NULL, &status);
    free(source);

    // Build Program
    status = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    size_t len;
    char *buffer;
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &len);
    buffer = (char *) malloc(len);
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, len, buffer, NULL);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    //Create Kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "multiply_arrays", &status);

    // Create Arrays with random Numbers
    cl_float a[NUM_ELEMENTS], b[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    random_fill(a, NUM_ELEMENTS);
    random_fill(b, NUM_ELEMENTS);

    //uint64_t startGPU = mach_absolute_time();
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    //Create Readonly input Buffers with value from a and b
    cl_mem inputA = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
        sizeof(cl_float) * NUM_ELEMENTS, a, NULL);
    cl_mem inputB = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
        sizeof(cl_float) * NUM_ELEMENTS, b, NULL);

    //Create Output buffer write Only
    cl_mem output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
        sizeof(cl_float) * NUM_ELEMENTS, NULL, NULL);

    //set Kernel Arguments
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &inputA);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &inputB);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);

    cl_event timing_event;
    size_t work_units = NUM_ELEMENTS;
    status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &work_units,
        NULL, 0, NULL,&timing_event);

    cl_float results[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    //Calculate Results and copy from output buffer to results
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, output, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * NUM_ELEMENTS,
        results, 0, NULL, NULL);

    //uint64_t endGPU = mach_absolute_time();
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //printf("Total (GPU): %lu ns\n\n", (unsigned long)(endGPU - startGPU));
    std::cout << "Total(GPU) :"<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish - start).count() << "ns\n";

    cl_ulong starttime;
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,
        sizeof(cl_ulong), &starttime, NULL);
    cl_ulong endtime;
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,
        sizeof(cl_ulong), &endtime, NULL);
    printf("Elapsed (GPU): %lu ns\n\n", (unsigned long)(endtime - starttime));
    clReleaseEvent(timing_event);
    clReleaseMemObject(inputA);
    clReleaseMemObject(inputB);
    clReleaseMemObject(output);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    //uint64_t startCPU = mach_absolute_time();
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i)
        results[i] = a[i] * b[i];

    //uint64_t endCPU = mach_absolute_time();
    finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    //printf("Elapsed (CPU): %lu ns\n\n", (unsigned long)(endCPU - startCPU));
    std::cout << "Elapsed (CPU) :" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish - start).count() << "ns\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**multiply_arrays.cl**

```
__kernel void multiply_arrays(__global const float* inputA,
    __global const float* inputB,
    __global float* output) {

    int i = get_global_id(0);
    output[i] = inputA[i] * inputB[i];
}
//Ã¶
```